# Script SQL that sums values of tables from different DBs

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I need a script that makes the sum of the `space_limit` from the `v$recovery_file_dest` from different databases:
I have a list of 5 DBs and I need it to connect to each one,save that value (space_limit) in memory and in the end give me the sum of all 5 values

Is it possible?

This is what i got so far, in the bottom i need it to show the sum:

```
undefine user  
accept user   char prompt 'User : '
undefine pswuser
accept pswuser   char prompt 'Password  : ' HIDE

set trimout off
set verify off
set markup html on

spool Z:\....\...\FRA_report_&data._&ora..html 

Prompt #####################################################
Prompt DATABASE 1
Prompt #####################################################
connect &user/&pswuser@DB1
select name, 
round(space_limit / 1024/ 1024), 
to_char(round(space_used / 1048576),'999g999g990','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.'),
round(((space_used / 1048576) / (space_limit / 1048576)*100),2)||'%'
from v$recovery_file_dest
/
```

*/.....And so on 5 times for each DB...../*

```
Prompt #####################################################
Prompt TOTAL FRA
Prompt #####################################################

spool off
set markup html off
disc
```

UPDATE:
I tried adding this for each DB

```
begin
 :total := total + v$recovery_file_dest.space_limit;
end;
/
```

But it gives me this error

*ERROR at line 2: 
ORA-06550: line 2, column 32: 
PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST.SPACE_LIMIT' not allowed in this context 
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2: 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored*

Comment: Connect to each one from where - within a single client session? From a shell/batch script? Are there database links from one of your DBs to the others?

Comment: I'm connecting from SQLPlus and not all DBs have links to each other!

Comment: It's not really clear where did you add the updated line in the script, please edit it so we can see it's location in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't that far off with your attempt to keep a running total, but you need to combine the bind variable and the table value in an SQL context:

```
begin
  select nvl(:total,0)  + sum(space_limit) into :total from v$recovery_file_dest;
end;
/
```

You can then either `print` the total, or to keep your HTML formatting query it from `dual`. So your script might end up looking like:

```
variable total number;

undefine user
accept user   char prompt 'User : '
undefine pswuser
accept pswuser   char prompt 'Password  : ' HIDE

set trimout off
set verify off
set markup html on
set numformat 999999999999

spool Z:\....\...\FRA_report_&data._&ora..html

Prompt #####################################################
Prompt DATABASE 1
Prompt #####################################################
connect &user/&pswuser@DB1
set feedback off

select name,
round(space_limit / 1024/ 1024),
to_char(round(space_used / 1048576),'999g999g990','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.'),
round(((space_used / 1048576) / (space_limit / 1048576)*100),2)||'%'
from v$recovery_file_dest
/

exec select nvl(:total,0)  + sum(space_limit) into :total from v$recovery_file_dest;

-- repeat for other databases

Prompt #####################################################
Prompt TOTAL FRA
Prompt #####################################################

select :total as total_fra, :total/(1024*1024) as total_fra_mb from dual;

spool off
set markup html off
disc
```

I've also added the variable declaration, and set the number format so it doesn't go into scientific notation for large values. You can, of course, manipulate the `:total` value to show it in MB or GB or whatever you prefer - I've shown the raw value and the MB value to match the individual database values.

I've also added `set feedback off`, which has to be repeated after each `connect` - some settings are reset whenever you reconnect.

That code produces output like this, when run with two databases listed:

```html
#####################################################
<br>
DATABASE 1
<br>
#####################################################
<br>
<p>
<table border='1' width='90%' align='center' summary='Script output'>
<tr>
<th scope="col">
NAME
</th>
<th scope="col">
ROUND(SPACE_LIMIT/1024/1024)
</th>
<th scope="col">
TO_CHAR(ROUN
</th>
<th scope="col">
ROUND(((SPACE_USED/1048576)/(SPACE_LIMIT/
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
+FRA
</td>
<td align="right">
        30720
</td>
<td>
      24.570
</td>
<td>
79.98%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
#####################################################
<br>
DATABASE 2
<br>
#####################################################
<br>
<p>
<table border='1' width='90%' align='center' summary='Script output'>
<tr>
<th scope="col">
NAME
</th>
<th scope="col">
ROUND(SPACE_LIMIT/1024/1024)
</th>
<th scope="col">
TO_CHAR(ROUN
</th>
<th scope="col">
ROUND(((SPACE_USED/1048576)/(SPACE_LIMIT/
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
+FRA
</td>
<td align="right">
        24576
</td>
<td>
      12.698
</td>
<td>
51.67%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
#####################################################
<br>
TOTAL FRA
<br>
#####################################################
<br>
<p>
<table border='1' width='90%' align='center' summary='Script output'>
<tr>
<th scope="col">
TOTAL_FRA
</th>
<th scope="col">
TOTAL_FRA_MB
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">
  57982058496
</td>
<td align="right">
        55296
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
```